# Having strange issue with CSS

Tags: html, css, width

Here is CSS

```
#content {
    margin-left:190px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Firefox & Opera result

[image]

Chrome Result

[image]

Tried to manually set `#content`'s width param to 90%. It 'fixed' issue.

Can anyone explain why this problem occurs and how can I fix it?

*Note: Css for left side bar is following*

```
#left {
    float:left;
    width:180px;
}
```

Comment: Create a minimal test case: strip things out until you've got as little as you can while still demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have any idea about the code structure you have, Please make a [fiddle] http://jsfiddle.net with minimum test case.

Check if your table inherit any float or width.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing code, but if those are tables you are using, one place you might possibly find answers (along with creating a minimal test case) would be looking into how different browsers handle tables/table css differently.  Historically, styling tables has always been a little bit inconsistent between browsers.